# JWT Exceptions on login, Username undefined

Tags: java, angular, typescript, jwt

Server-side:

I have an app in Spring Boot on the server side and TypeScript with Angular on the client side. I am implementing a login, but when I send the data to the server, it doesn't capture the username from the JWT and sets it as undefined.

This is the server code that sends the username from the client, but it doesn't find it in the database even though it exists:

```
public String getSessionUsername() {
    if (oHttpServletRequest.getAttribute("username") instanceof String) {
        return oHttpServletRequest.getAttribute("username").toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

// This part of the code throws an exception that the user is not found

```
public Boolean isAdmin() {
    if (this.getSessionUsername() != null) {
        UserEntity oUserEntityInSession = oUserRepository.findByUsername(this.getSessionUsername())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found"));
        return Boolean.FALSE.equals(oUserEntityInSession.getRole());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Client-side:

The client-side code seems to capture the username correctly and indicates that I am logged in, but it doesn't do anything because the variable strUserName is empty:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
        console.log("Username:", this.loginForm.value.username);
        this.oSessionService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.oCryptoService.getSHA256(this.loginForm.value.password)).subscribe({
            next: (data: string) => {
                console.log(this.loginForm.value.username);
                this.oSessionService.setToken(data);
                console.log(data);
                this.oSessionService.emit({ type: 'login' });
                this.oMatSnackBar.open("Login successful.", '', { duration: 2000 });
                this.oRouter.navigate(['/home']);
            },
            error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                this.status = error;
                this.oMatSnackBar.open("Error in login operation.", '', { duration: 2000 });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

// This code captures the username correctly, but the variable

```
`strUserName` remains empty
this.strUserName = this.oSessionService.getUsername();
console.log(this.strUserName);
this.oUserAjaxService.getByUsername(this.oSessionService.getUsername()).subscribe({
    next: (oUser: IUser) => {
        this.oSessionUser = oUser;
    },
    error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The getUsername function in the service is expected to return the username from the session:

```
getUsername(): string {
    if (this.isSessionActive()) {
        let token: string | null = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (!token) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return this.parseJwt(token).name;
        }
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need further assistance or clarification on any part of the code.

Im trying to send a username to the server side but the program sent undefined

Comment: Make sure the value you submit to BE is not empty. Did you see the username on the console.log ?